# Oracle JIT inlining

Tags: java, jit

Is there a comprehensive documentation about the JIT for the various JVMs? I was struck by lightning, that for the following scenario I just *hope* that JIT will do the right thing, but I cannot find any documentation about whether my hope if justified or not.

The scenario:

```
if (complexCondition(myObject) && effectivelyStaticBoolean) {
    ...
}
```

`effectivelyStaticBoolean` is read once at the instantiation of the class, and is effectively static final, meaning that in the same JVM it will always be either `true` or `false`, but never change behaviour (most basic example would be `StringUtils.containsIgnorecase(System.getProperty("os.name"), "win");`)

`complexCondition(myObject)` depends on the actual object instance and is costly to check.

My hope: JIT will kick in, and if `effectivelyStaticBoolean == false`, then eventually (if it is determined as hot) no evaluation for the `complexCondition(...)` will take place.

Is my hope justified? (Especially for Oracle JVM, but I'm interested in the answer for other mainstream JVMs too)

Comment: Depends if it can figure out that `complexCondition` is free of side effects.  (If it's complex...probably not.)  Of course, you could always just reverse the check and write `effectivelyStaticBoolean && complexCondition(myObject)`, which will always do the right thing immediately.

Comment: @louiswasserman yes, exactly, I bumped into the question during code review, and I'm tempted to add a comment "please swap the two", because then it's obvious based on the fact that `&&` is short-circuit. But the original question is still interesting IMO.

Interesting notion about side-effect freeness. Does it really matter, if for example `effectivelyStaticBoolean` is `final`?

Comment: It's not `effectivelyStaticBoolean`, but `complexCondition`, where it is important.  Definitely make your comment; even if the JIT could do it it'd be better to make it obvious.

Comment: If I write `private final effectivelyStaticBoolean = false` in my class, then `complexCondition` may or may not have side-effect, as long as it is free of reflection, it does not matter.

Comment: Not true.  `complexCondition(...) && false` must still evaluate `complexCondition`.  If it has side effects, those side effects will always happen, and the JIT must keep it that way.

Comment: Huh, good point. Nevertheless the question stays open: is there a good/thorough documentation about the different JITs somewhere? (E.g., how does it determine whether a function call is side-effect free)

Comment: JITs are usually barely documented black magic boxes.  I would not expect to find documentation on this, certainly not anything thorough or that you could rely on to predict results.

Comment: You should reverse the test, make the comment, whatever. Code should not be written to rely on obscure properties of the implementation, whether favourable or unfavourable.